# Bootstrap collapse dependendo de valor

Tags: bootstrap-3, bootstrap, collapse

Eu tenho uma tabela, com algumas linhas "colapsadas" e todas com checkbox, para seleção. Estou utilizando o data-toggle="collapse", porém não está me atendendo muito bem.

O que eu preciso é:

- Clicar no checkbox "Selecionar Todos", deve abrir todas as linhas "colapsadas" e selecionar todos os checkbox;
- Clicar no checkbox de Cliente (a linha que trigga o collapse), deve abrir as linhas "colapsadas" deste cliente e selecionar os checkbox dessas linhas;
- Selecionar todos os checkbox das linhas dentro de um cliente, seleciona o checkbox do cliente
- Tirar a seleção de 1 checkbox das linhas dentro do um cliente, desmarca o checkbox do cliente, se estiver checado

A parte de selecionar os checkbox eu fiz tranquilo, mas estou apanhando para o collapse, pois selecionar o checkbox, trigga o collapse e ele se perde todo ao trocar o ícone e "colapsar" as linhas.

Tem uma forma simples de "abrir/fechar" os collapse? Ou é mais fácil "criar" o collapse do zero e não usar o do bootstrap?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver! O bootstrap tem alguns métodos que mostram ou escondem o collapse:

```
.collapse('show/hide/toggle')
```